# how to convert json string to javascript array in jsp?

Tags: json, gson

In my jsp below is code.how to access (String jsonname)in javascript  as javascript array? currently, it doesnot print anything.

```
   ArrayList<String> name=new ArrayList<String>();   
   name.add("Ravi");
   name.add("Vijay");    
   name.add("Ajay");    
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String jsonname = gson.toJson(name);
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var name = JSON.parse(jsonname);// not working
   </script>
```

Comment: can you print out the value of `jsonname` ?

Comment: @Ahmad["Ravi","Vijay","Ajay"]

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It is possible to use JSON.parse on arrays

Comment: @Ahmad then, how can i convert java Arraylist to javascript Array?

Comment: What error is reported when you try the code above?

Comment: @Ahmad print nothing

Comment: @Ahmad that was  my typing error, i have correct code. but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You've named your `ArrayList` `name`, but you're trying to add to `list`

#### Solution

```
ArrayList<String> name=new ArrayList<String>();   
   name.add("Ravi");
   name.add("Vijay");    
   name.add("Ajay");    
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String jsonname = gson.toJson(name);
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var name = JSON.parse(jsonname);// not working
   </script>
```